# android - how to open maps application directly

Tags: android, maps

In my application i want to show the direction between two geo points.For i used the maps application. but it shows the different options provided by mobile like following image.But i want to show the direction without asking this. is it possible? please can anybody help me.

```
String directionweburl = "http://maps.google.com/maps?daddr="+dest_lat+","+dest_long+"&saddr="+source_lat+","+source_long;

Intent myIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(directionweburl));

startActivity(myIntent);
```

[image]

Updated

Initially it shows like following

[image]

But i want to show directly like following is it possible?

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You just need to go through this http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/g-app-intents.html.

You will find `The Geo URI scheme (not fully supported) is currently under development.`. for supporting your url request. So I think you have to try another way as the current way takes only latitude, longitude, zoom and query features.

**Edit :** You can try setting up class name for google maps activity for removing this Dialog :

```
String directionweburl = "http://maps.google.com/maps?daddr="+dest_lat+","+dest_long+"&saddr="+source_lat+","+source_long;

Intent myIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(directionweburl));
intent.setClassName("com.google.android.apps.maps", "com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity");
startActivity(myIntent);
```

**Edit 2** (dont try its not working)
Try setting this class name :

```
intent.setClassName("com.google.android.apps.maps",
"com.google.android.maps.driveabout.app.NavigationActivity");
```

Comment: try intent.setClassName("com.google.android.apps.m4ps",
"com.google.android.maps.driveabout.app.NavigationActivity");

Comment: it's not working it shows navigation alert. and one more thing it's "maps" not "m4ps" right?

Answer (score 0):

String directionweburl = "http://maps.google.com/maps?daddr="+dest_lat+","+dest_long+"&saddr="+source_lat+","+source_long;

Intent myIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(directionweburl));
intent.setClassName("com.google.android.apps.maps", "com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity");
startActivity(myIntent);

its working 
if any problem occurs use google Api simulator

Answer (score 0):

String directionweburl = "http://maps.google.com/maps?daddr="+dest_lat+","+dest_long+"&saddr="+source_lat+","+source_long;

Intent myIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(directionweburl)); intent.setClassName("com.google.android.apps.maps", "com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity"); startActivity(myIntent);